# Decrement a For Loop?

Tags: xcode, for-loop, decrement

I can increment a FOR loop in xcode, but for some reason the reverse, namely decrementing, doesn't work.

This incrementing works fine, of course:

```
for (int i=0; i<10; ++i) {
    NSLog(@"i =%d", i);
}
```

But, this decrementing doesn't produce a thing:

```
for (int i=10; i<0; --i) {
    NSLog(@"i =%d", i);
}
```

I must have the syntax wrong, but I believe this is correct for Objective C++ in xcode.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think you mean `>`  instead of  `<`:

```
for (int i = 10; i > 0; --i) {
```

If you want the values of i to be the same as in the original code except in reverse order (i.e. 9, 8, 7, ..., 1, 0) then you also need to change the boundaries:

```
for (int i = 9; i >= 0; --i) {
```

Comment: Note that the latter works fine for signed types like `int` but will underflow for types like `size_t` (and thus never terminate). Instead, use `for (size_t index = your_size; index--;)`

Answer (score 5):

I just want to add to keep in mind that `--i` decrements first, then checks and  `i--` checks, then decrements.

Answer (score 2):

You are checking `i < 0`. This is false in the first iteration and thus the loop isn't executed. Change it to `i > 0` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You need the condition to be i>0 (if i starts at 10, then 10<0 is false, so it never executes the loop code).

Answer (score 1):

`for (int i = 10; --i >= 0;) {`

is a neat way to express the for loop in @Mark Byers answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change the termination condition from `i<0` to `i>0`

Comment: Oh, this is so different from the FOR loop logic I'm used to in other ancient programming languages. I thought that the condition was testing for i counting down from 10 until i got to 1. This seems counter-intuitive, but it works. Thanks a million.